# OPC (server and client) with python

Tags: python, automation, plc, opc, siemens

I need to build my own OPC (server and client) with python via ethernet.
So I can put the ip address of the PLC and the address of the input or output.
Please if someone have any example of this.

Comment: There is number of libraries for Python. OPS may be UA, DA or other. And those are COMPLETELY different things. Start with your own investigation and then ask more particular questions. As an answer to this one, I could write 300 pages book.

Comment: is there a way so i can start ?

Comment: Hard to tell. Do you know Python? иecuase you sound like you are not even familiar with language itself.

Comment: @SergeyRomanov i made a beginning training in order to build my own OPC because I need it.